# Search String and If found then paste value - then loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a macro that searches a column for two Strings ("Tip Fee" or "Non-Deal". If it finds this then it pastes a "Y" value in another column. If it doesn't then it pastes "N".

I'm struggling to get it to work and not sure what to do for the "not equal to then "N") part.

Example for just finding "Tip Fee" below:

```
Sheets("Pipeline simplified").Select

Dim TipFee As String
Dim NonDeal As String
Dim t As Integer
Dim LastRowtip As Long
TipFee = "Tip Fee"
NonDeal = "Non-Deal"
LastRowtip = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row


For t = 7 To LastRowtip

    If Cells(t, 8).Value = TipFee Then
    Cells(t, 30).Value = "Y"
      End If
Next t
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you mean that if it finds `Tip Fee` **or** `Non-Deal` then paste `Y`?

Comment: Yes that's right sry. "Tip Fee or "Non-Deal". Tried to get it to work for just "Tip Fee" in above example but couldn't even get that to work. Not sure why

Comment: Does this need to be VBA? You can do this with a formula.  In cell AD7 use this formula and copy down: `=IF(OR(H7={"Tip Fee","Non-Deal"}),"Y","N")`

Comment: Welcome to SO, @SuperLoz. You don't need VBA for this, unless it's the first step of a larger project. You can use an if statement in your Y/N column: `=IF(OR($H7="Tip Fee",$H7="Non-Deal"),"Y","N")` and then drag that down.

Comment: @tigeravatar Apparently you beat me to it.

Comment: You can even calculate the output: `=CHAR(78+OR($H7="Tip Fee",$H7="Non-Deal")*11)`

Comment: Hi All - yes It's part of a larger VBA macro code - so want to avoid Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can still use a formula in VBA, that way there's no need to loop.  Formula can be made to search for text within the cell, and can also be case insensitive.  Then just convert to values afterwards.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pipeline simplified")

With ws.Range("AD7:AD" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""Tip Fee"",""Non-Deal""},H7))),""Y"",""N"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for this - ended up using this and last row

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If Cells(t, 8).Value = TipFee Or Cells(t, 8).Value = NonDeal Then
    Cells(t, 30).Value = "Y"
Else
    Cells(t, 30).Value = "N"
End If
```

Also, check how IF sentence works:

> **[If...Then...Else statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement)**

Comment: Thanks Fox. What was wrong with my code? This helped but it's filled all the cells with "N". When there are a number with Tip Fee in the name: Example: Plus S.p.A (Tip Fee)

Comment: Note: `If` statements couldn't care less about case sensitivity - what's at play is the default string comparison mode which is `Binary` by default (`Option Compare Binary`). `Option Compare Text` makes comparisons case-insensitive. The `StrComp` function takes a comparison mode argument so string comparisons can be made case-[in]sensitive without affecting the entire module with an `Option` at the top; if `StrComp` returns `0`, the two strings are equivalent.

Comment: *what's at play is the default string comparison mode which is Binary by default (Option Compare Binary)* You are absolutely right @MathieuGuindon. Default one is binary, not the IF statement by itself.

Comment: @SuperLoz If it filled all cells with `N` it means that the relative cell in column H same row **is not exactly equal to** `Tip Fee` or `Non-Deal`. If you post a data example, maybe we can help you out

Comment: Upvoted - I'd probably extract the condition into its own variable, and then go `Cells(t, 30).Value = IIf(isTipFreeOrNonDeal, "Y", "N")` to avoid assigning the same thing different values in two mutually exclusive conditional branches, but that's just me =)  @SuperLoz watch out for unqualified `Cells`, `Ranges`, `Rows`, `Columns`, and `Names` calls: unless you're in a specific worksheet's code-behind module, these unqualified member calls all implicitly refer to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. If the wrong sheet happens to be active when the condition runs, could explain why it's not working.

Comment: Combining this idea with comments from @MathieuGuindon, change the first line to the following: `If StrComp(Cells(t, 8).Value, TipFee, vbTextCompare) = 0 Or StrComp(Cells(t, 8).Value, NonDeal, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`